# Rails :confirm modifier callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, unobtrusive-javascript, link-to, view-helpers, link-to-remote

I want to call a javascript function that will be conditional upon a user's response to the confirm box.

For example, I have the following anchor:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_session_path, confirm: 'Are you sure that you would like to sign out?', method: :delete %>
```

Should I just abandon the unobtrusive javascript and bind my own jQuery callback to my anchor?

Or is there some magical way to pass a callback function to the Rails url helper? I did not see any discussion of callbacks in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By following the `link_to` source, I see that the `:confirm` modifier is passed to the [convert_options_to_data_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/convert_options_to_data_attributes) method, which points to the [ujs script](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) that is bundled with Rails these days (the unobtrusive javascript via jQuery). Here we find that ultimately the user's response is passed to an event called `confirm:complete` by using the `data-confirm` attribute in the html.

So it appears that the answer is "no, you cannot pass a callback through the url helper". But you can put a callback in your `app/javascript` to listen for this event. This seems to be the most unobtrusive way to accomplish my goal, considering that I am still letting rails handle the event prevention and propagation. I wait for all of this to happen, and then call my function.

```
$(document).on('confirm:complete', function (e, answer) {
  if (answer) {
    // user confirmed!
    myCallbackFunction();
  } else {
    // user canceled!
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue ([How to use inline :confirm option for html helpers with AJAX calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959047/how-to-use-inline-confirm-option-for-html-helpers-with-ajax-calls)). @Micah's answer, even though works, is not what "Rails 3 way" would be.

1. remote: true option needs to be added to the link_to helper, e.g.

`link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_session_path, remote: true, confirm: 'Are you sure that you would like to sign out?', method: :delete`

2. In the controller change `respond_to` block to answer to js
3. create a js file with the name that corresponds to your method, e.g. destroy_session.js.coffee

#### app/views/competitions/destroy_session.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $("form[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').fadeOut()`
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, the accepted answer didn't work for me. I ended up doing something like this instead:

```js
$(document).on('confirm:complete', function (e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.detail[0]) {
    // user confirmed!
    myCallbackFunction();
  } else {
    // user canceled!
  }
});
```